# Can this  question be deleted?

Tags: support

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88338/how-to-enumerate-all-the-possible-7-digit-phone-numbers

I tried to delete it but I could not. I understand it is vague and hopefully in the future will formulate my questions more precisely.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want it deleted, or do you want it migrated to one of the computer science Stack Exchanges? (StackOverflow, for example?)

Comment: I am not familiar with Stack Overflow, but I reckon even in CS terms it is imprecise. I'd rather have it deleted.

Answer (score 3):

Done. There were already 4 votes to close, so I cast to final vote as off topic and then deleted the question.

Comment: Thank you very much.